# Istio virtualservice issue for Airflow webservice

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, istio

I am trying to setup istio for Airflow webservice
My current airflow url is http://myorg.com:8080/appv1/airflow (without istio)

After i tried to integrate with istio i have written the virtual service as given below but i end up getting a 404 Not Found. I am trying to access the url from http://myorg.com/v1airlfow

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: airflow-vservice
  namespace: "{{ .Release.Namespace }}"
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - airflow-gateway
  http:
  - name: airflow-http
    match:
    - uri:
        exact: "/v1airflow"
    - uri:
        exact: "/v1airflow/"
    rewrite:            
      uri: "/appv1/airflow/"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: {{ .Release.Name }}-airflow-web.{{ .Release.Namespace }}.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
    headers:
      request:
        set:
          X-Forwarded-Proto: "http"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: airflow-gateway
  namespace: "{{ .Release.Namespace }}"
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: airflow-http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

Comment: Hi, what platform are you using? What k8s and istio versions do You use?

Comment: @PiotrMalec - i use istio 1.5.0 and k8s 1.16.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- uri:
      prefix: "/v1airflow"

  - uri:
    prefix: "/v1airflow/home"
  - uri:
    prefix: "/v1airflow/static"
  - uri:
    prefix: "/v1airflow/login"
  - rewrite:
    regex: ^/v1airflow/(.*)$

Got it working